# Output is coming out to be Greater than sign(>)

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the question:

[image: This is the question image, the question is itself pretty simple]

I've written my code solution in JavaScript and as it's on CODECHEF, I gotta run it on NodeJs environment. But on submission, it shows the time limit exceeded, and on custom input, it outputs the Greater than sign(>).I strongly believe that the problem is with my input, I think its not right, please help. The following is my code:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var readline = require('readline');
 
var rl = readline.createInterface(
        process.stdin, process.stdout);
 
//rl.setPrompt(`What is your age? `);
rl.prompt();


rl.on('line', (num) => {

  var reverseNum;

    
  reverseNum = function(num) {
      for(let i=0;i<num;i++) {
        let r = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
        //let final =  Math.sign(num) * parseInt(r);
        console.log( Math.sign(num) * parseInt(r));
      }
  }
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Which question is it? Can you put a link to the question?

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA01/problems/FLOW007

Comment: Please check the answer I've posted, it should solve you issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Always process input `.on('data')` and output `.on('end')`.

> AC Solution Below [(Question)](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW007)

[image]

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf8");

var input = "";
var arr;

process.stdin.on("data", function (data) {
  input += data;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
  arr = input.split("\n");
  arr.slice(1).forEach((a) => {
    console.log(a.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/^0*/, ""));
  });
});
```

> Reversing Logic

```js
const 
  str = "2300",
  reversed = str.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/^0*/, "");

console.log(reversed);
```

Comment: I really appreciate the efforts but, As I'm running it with custom input, it's working perfectly but on submitting it still prompts the wrong answer!!

Comment: @ParthArora Please check with the updated answer, I got AC with this.

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked. could you explain why the replace() function worked?

Comment: `Number("312873218387136127821321")` will result in `3.1287321838713614e+23`, whereas replace would just replace the leading zeroes.

Comment: Got it, Thank you much. Appreciate your time!!